# "More than one file was found with OS independent path" error when the same .jar is a dependency for both the app and a module

Tags: android, gradle

I have a project with an app and a java library module called "Emulator."  Both the app and the module require bluecove-2.1.0.jar as a dependency.  I added bluecove-2.1.0.jar to the libs folder for the app and the module, and I was able to successfully assemble the module and generate an Emulator.jar. However, when I build the app, I encounter the following error:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'bluecove-2.1.0.51.version'

**Is there a way to share the bluecover-2.1.0.jar library with both the app and the module without adding it to both lib folders and adding it as a dependency in both build.gradle files?** I'm assuming this is what's responsible for the error since I was able to build the app sucessfully with the bluecove-2.1.0.jar before it became dependent on the module which also uses the bluecove-2.1.0.jar.

app build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation project(":Emulator")
    implementation files('libs/bluecove-2.1.0.jar')
}
```

Emulator module build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation files('libs/bluecove-2.1.0.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: add the .jar as its own Module then create dependencies in both the app and emulator Modules.

*Android Studio 3.4:

Steps for adding .jar as its own Module:

1. File -> Project Structure
2. Select the Modules tab on the left
3. Click the + button
4. Scroll down and choose "Import .JAR/AAR Package"
5. Enter the path where the .jar is in your computer's file system and
   give the Module a name
6. Click Finish

Steps to add the new .jar Module as dependencies:

1. File -> Project Structure
2. Select the Dependencies tab on the left
3. Select the app Module tab
4. Click + button underneath the "Declared Dependencies" Header (other + button adds a new Module) and choose option 3 "Module Dependency"
5. Select the new .jar Module you just added
6. Repeat steps 3 through 5 for the Emulator Module
7. Click Apply then Ok

Comment: This fixed the issue. After creating new modules from the imported bluecove-2.1.0.jar, I changed `implementation files('libs/bluecove-2.1.0.jar')` to `implementation project(":bluecove-2.1.0")` in the `build.gradle` and it worked.